# Is There A Fast Way To Add Multiple Text boxes With Scrollbars?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, scrollbar

Because the cells in my project contain so much data I have had to insert textboxes that have scrollbars to see all the data (they are linked to the cell which sit behind them on the spreadsheet). Is there any fast way to do the same thing on a column of 1000 records or will I have to go through manually and link the textbox to the specific cell? Is there a faster way?

Also If an issue comes in that is a reply to the original issue I need it to use the original ID (I have used auto IDS, which can be seen in the spreadsheet). Any recommendations?

Slowly I am getting better at excel and VBA but I need a hand sometimes ^_^

I have attached the spreadsheet which contains an example of 2 records I made. The final sheet will have 1000 records. (Please download the spreadsheet and open in excel)

[LINK To Spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8OtUevU1V5sVkdndDd2UldxMHM)

Comment: You could just have one textbox on the sheet and move it around in response to the selected row changing.

Comment: hmmm, So if a user presses on the row for example the text box will follow? Only issue is that say the users want to see more than one issue I will need multiple boxes. How would I implement the one textbox idea? Does my spreadsheet make the issue I am having anymore understandable? Its hard to explain.

Comment: I tried to look at your file but it consistently crashes my Excel...  As to how you'd move the textbox, you can use the selection_change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. You should change the cell formatting to "Top Align" the text in the cells.  This will cause the cell to show the first line of the long text in the Query cells.
2. Instead of using the "send email" text in a cell why not add a single button to email the currently selected row.  (use insert on the ribbon in the developer tab (you have to change the excel options to show the developer tab).
3. The code to send an email might be better if it updated a new column with the date it was sent, and in the event that it has already been sent, it could prompt the user to confirm.

   if not isempty(cells(r, ColNumberWithSentdate) ) then 
       if vbno = msgbox ("Are you sure you want to send the email again?", VbYesno) then
           Exit sub
       end if
   end if
4. All the textboxes you have added are really slowing down the spreadsheet.
   why not just have one tall row at the top above the table with the filters.  The tall row would show the data from the currently selected row in the table.  Your table rows could then probably be less high.
5. Add a single text box.
   Use ALT+click and drag to resize text boxes to fit cell exactly.
   Change or view the name of the textbox in the named range area to "TextBoxQuery".
6. Add code to change the text in the summary row

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

       ' Say the tall row is in row 2
       If Target.Row <= 2 Then
           Exit Sub
       End If

       Dim i As Integer
       For i = 1 To 8
           Cells(2, i) = Cells(Target.Row, i)
       Next i


   End Sub
   ```
7. You could even allow the user to edit the text in the tall row and add a button to save the changes they entered:

A. Add  an ACTIVEX button in the summary row labelled "SAVE"
   (Then you can edit the vba in the sheets module for the button)

B. Add a cell somewhere that records which row is being displayed in the summary row.

C. When the save button is clicked, write code that copies all the values in row to back to the row recorded.

NOTE that if the user deletes a row in the table or sorts the data in the table the row stored will be wrong. So before copying the data, you might like to check to see whether the row has moved. ie check a KEY value (ie ones that never changes) is the saem in both rows.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 8
        Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, i) = Cells(2, i)
    Next i


End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Say the tall row is in row 2
    If Target.Row <= 2 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Cell A1 is used to store which row is displayed
    Cells(1, 1) = Target.Row

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 8
        Cells(2, i) = Cells(Target.Row, i)
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Harvey, Thanks for the response and looking at my really messy spreadsheet. How would I do it so I can select the row and it appears in a big tall row? (sounds like a really good idea that but unsure how to implement it). Also would I implement the single text box in the big row above so its just 1 text box? How does that code know which row I have select to implent into the text box? Sorry for all the questions

Comment: The code I added changes the formula of the textbox you are using to display values that sits over the query column of the tall row.  You could have multiple textboxes, one for each column OR you could use formulas in the cells of the tall row and write similar code to change the formula in the big row's cells.

It's worth noting that users will not be able to edit

Comment: @user  Sorry I had a better idea.  See latest code in answer

Comment: Kinda confused here. So how does this work? I make a tall row in column 2 that bring in the information from below? Only issue is The query column gets a lot of data so unsure it will all be viewable.

Comment: Yes you make a tall "summary" row in ROW 2.  You can put a text box over the query column if you want to have scroll bars.

Comment: Excellent. This is kick ass man. Say when a user fills in the reply and their Case Owner in the Summery row can I make that auto update in the rows below? If so how?